# navigation controller uri from host and scheme for deeplinks

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components

I had perfectly working oauth redirect intent filter

```
<data
android:host="${host}"
android:scheme="${scheme}" />
```

where host and scheme was set in app gradle as manifestPlaceholders:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [host: "goodreads", scheme: "oauth"]
```

and so my activity recieved oauth redirect.

Now I'm moving my apps' navigation to new handy navigation controller, but I can't solve how to proper convert host and scheme into deeplink uri. I've tried this:

```
<deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deepLink"
        app:uri="oauth://goodreads" />
```

for the receiving fragment.

and instead of intent-filter in activity host of the navigation controller I've inserted this:

```
<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

now I'm

but this didn't work. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

I've also tried to decompress my resulted apk to see the generated intent filter and it looks like this:

```
<data android:scheme="oauth"/>
<data android:host="goodreads"/>
<data android:path="/"/>
```

How could I generate the proper uri?

upd:
my whole nav_graph looks like this: https://gist.github.com/intmainreturn00/0e4c4121c2cd952370b4838b597a5d01

and my manifest :
https://gist.github.com/intmainreturn00/e7e4ca261d38c4dfb786ba3f8de15918

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: interesting question. 3.4..why?

Comment: The expansion of `<nav-graph>` into `<intent-filter>` is tied to the version of the Android Gradle Plugin/Android Studio version you're using, so using 3.4 will mean that you don't have any of the fixes in 3.5+

Comment: thanks for the interesting comment. I will try. This is still in beta, right?

Comment: Correct, 3.5 is in beta right now and 3.6 is in Canary

Comment: unfortunately, canary build gives the same result =(

Comment: Can you post your full navigation xml file? I suspect your `<deepLink>` element isn't in the right place

Comment: I've updated my question with gists with navigation graph and manifest.

Comment: @AndreySuvorov could you solved it? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @rguerra technically no, I end up changing the original OAuth redirect url at host to oauth://goodreads/ with slash to fit the autogenerated deeplink